# TouchWiz (easy mode) launched when home button pressed from my app on Samsung phones

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a published app reported by users.
It happens in Samsung phones and the problem is with their Easy Mode or TouchWiz, when I press the physical home button the phone ask if you want to use TouchWiz.
See pic:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening and because of that I don't know which code should I upload.

Do you have any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: It looks like this is just the users fault for not choosing a default launcher app. You can check it for yourself. Install a second launcher like Nova Launcher from the play store and press the home button. Your phone should then ask you what launcher you want to use and if you want to set is as a default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "home button on app" (btw most android apps do not have a home button) do you mean a button that does an ACTION_HOME?  If so this is expected-  this will bring up a list of apps that claim to implement ACTION_HOME, all of which really should be launchers.  Unless you're writing a kiosk mode app, ACTION_HOME isn't something you should be using-  you should instead do a direct intent to your home activity.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well sorry about that. Im not overriding any behavior. When I say home button im talking about the physical phone button.

Comment: Then this would be expected if there was not a default home app set on the device.

Comment: So why my app is elegible to be a home app if im not doing anything to do it?

Comment: Post your manifest.  You probably have an intent filter in there you forgot or didn't realize what it was doing

Comment: The problem was a tag in my MenuActivity: <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />. So you were right, thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

My problem was that I had the tag in my main activity.